# Physical Layer: How do how frequency sources work?

Tags: high-frequency

This is likely basic: but how do the source that rapidly generate 0-1s thru a channel "work" so fast? If it is a electric signal that is the source [as it is I believe even for fiber optic where a source converts electric signals to light pulses to be transmitted along the fiber]: how are these high frequency signals generated?

I am thinking that there must be some "moving part"/mechanical part that "vibrates" so fast:  but can we really have mechanical parts vibrating that fast? Or is there a frequency amplification from the mechanical to electrical that happens?

Comment: Indeed, there are mechanical parts that can vibrate that fast: [crystal oscillators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator).  Fundamental frequency can be in tens of MHz.  Indeed, there are also are electrical circuits that can multiply frequency: [phase lock loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of frequencies are you talking about? You can use crystals up to something like 50 MHz after which they become tricky to use.

Higher frequencies are often generated by VCO (Voltage Controlled Oscillator) circuits, which can generate frequencies of several gigahertz, but are themselves not very accurate. They are made accurate by a technique called Phase Locked Looping (PLL), where a digital divider circuit is used to divide the high frequency by some integer factor, for example 64, 128 or 100. Then the divided frequency is compared to a frequency of a crystal and the control voltage of the VCO is adjusted accordingly to make it stay at the desired frequency.

Answer (score 0):

It's called an oscillator and can contain a small crystal that does mechanically vibrate in the MHz range quite easily. Get above 100 MHz and crystals are starting to be ineffective in common oscillator circuits so an inductor-capacitor (LC) circuit can be effectively used well beyond 1 GHz. To obtain crystal-like accuracy and low drift a phase-locked-loop circuit is employed.

There are other oscillator circuits too but crystal and LC are the common ones covering the biggest range of frequencies someone may want to generate.

Comment: It's not hard at all to find packaged crystal oscillator circuits that operate up to maybe 300 MHz. [For example](http://vectron.com/products/xo/vc-806.htm). Of course, they operate by exciting a harmonic of the crystal's natural resonance frequency rather than the fundamental.